# Difference between AlarmManager and ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: android, scheduling, alarmmanager

Besides setting and exact time (i.e. midnight) versus setting a delay (i.e. 24 hours), what's the difference between using `AlarmManager` and `ScheduledExecutorService` to run a task periodically?

In my case, I need to run a little bit of code to check for new data every night and create a new notification if there is new data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`ScheduledExecutorService` runs in your application process. If application process dies, none of the scheduled tasks will run. Hence the need for `Service` (so your process lives beyond Activities active part of lifecycle).

While `AlarmManager` is critical system service that runs all the time. And if your application scheduled something and was killed, then `AlarmManager` may start application again (via `PendingIntent`).

And the last major difference that no one mentioned here is that `AlarmManager` knows about `WakeLock`s and power management. This means that `AlarmManager` may wake up Android device at specified time to run scheduled task. While `ScheduledExecutorService` knows nothing about power management and will only start task when device is not in deep sleep (i.e. it can simply miss the time).

Comment: Is there anything else which will work when the device is in deep sleep.. I tried Handler, Runnable Threads, nothing work in deep sleep mode.

Answer (score 13):

`ScheduledExecutorService` will only work if you have some component, such as a `Service`, running all of the time. Hence, it should only be used in cases where the component would be in memory for other reasons, adding value to the user. Having a component be in memory solely to watch the clock tick by is wasteful and one of the reasons why users attack developers with task killers and such.

`AlarmManager` is an OS-supplied system service. It can start up a component when the time rolls around. Hence, you do not need to have the component running.

> In my case, I need to run a little bit of code to check for new data every night and create a new notification if there is new data.

This is a clear scenario for `AlarmManager`.

Answer (score 5):

I think `ScheduledExecutorService` is tied to your process and will not work in case your process gets killed. In contrast `AlarmManager` is managed by the OS so it works even if your application is not running.