# AutoStart Application not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-manifest

I am having a Simple `AutoStart` Application with `TimerTask` implementation, that works fine in almost many devices. The problem is that it is not working in `Samsung Galaxy Y(2.3.6)` and `DELL XCD35(2.2)`. When the device boots `TimerTask` works for some seconds and then shuts down. I check in the `Application->Manage Application`, I saw that the Applcation was already in `Force Stop` State. That means some how my Application gets stopped after some seconds. So, what is the reason for this `weird behaviour` in these two devices, if anyone has the solution do share it.

Below is my code.

**MyReceiver.java**

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    private Timer mTimer = new Timer();
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Device Booted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("TAG","Device Booted");
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTimerTask(), 2000,2000);
    }

    private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("TAG","TimerTask executed....");
        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.autostart.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Ah!!! any reason about down vote?

Comment: A valid, good formatted question, no need for a down vote...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in some of the `Android` `OS` sometimes the OS kills the threads that are running while the `Devices` `Boots` which Android is not familiar with or doesn't recognize it. This is the reason why the `TimerTask` is working in some Devices and in some Devices just works for a 5-10 seconds and then the Application is `ForceStopped` `automatically` by the Android OS on `Device` `Boot`(*Note - Its Force Stop from Manage Application and not Force close so I am not getting any error in the Logcat*).

So in that case the solution is to use the `inbuilt` `Mechanism` which `Android` `OS` recognizes and doesn't kill it and keeps it in a running mode. In this case I managed using `AlarmManager` to perform my task and it works.

I might not be right but my final solution was to use `AlarmManager` to make my Application working in every Device.

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.
                                         getService(context, 0, myIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                                    .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                      System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000, 2000, pendingIntent);
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

[`AlaramManager is critical system service that runs all the time.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558694/difference-between-alarmmanager-and-scheduledexecutorservice)

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you to use AlarmManager instead of TimerTask, as I faced the same problem you described in many devices.

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Device Booted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("TAG","Device Booted");
AlarmManager AM =(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("ALARM_MANAGER_ACTION");//can add any string action here
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext
                                        .getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,0);
AM.set(AlarmManager.RTC,selectedTime, pi);
AM.setRepeating(AM.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+2000, 2000, pi);
    }


  public class MyReceiver1 extends BroadcastReceiver{ 
  //event will come here
  private Timer mTimer = new Timer();
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
 // check if event is same as you broadcasted through alarmManager
    Toast.makeText(context, "Device Booted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     Log.d("TAG","TimerTask executed....");

}
```

add a Broadcast receiver in your app, which should listen `("ALARM_MANAGER_ACTION")` action. and add this action into manifest file.
I bet it will work in these two devices as well.