# To start my Application while screen is locked?

Tags: android, locking, screen

I want to continue running my application when the back light and screen lock. Is it possible or not. Anybody kindly guide me?

```
timer Function
receiver
```

are running in Background. Inside the receiver I am getting the Data.

Comment: can you explain the actual requirement ?

Comment: explain in detail , why you want to do so. and With application what do u mean , Service and receivers always there in background

Comment: samething i am doing, but it is working in my phone even if it is locked

Comment: @lucifer How, is it possible?

Comment: I am using HTC Tatoo & Reliance Tablet... and it is working fine, which device ,you are using ? you can join me in my chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6137/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here Code tht will help you

```
KeyguardManager   mKeyGuardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock   mLock = mKeyGuardManager.newKeyguardLock("activity_classname");
mLock.disableKeyguard();
```

And this is the [Reference Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/activity_testing.html#UnlockDevice)

Comment: is any other way to solve the problem ?to disable the lock is not gud

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `Timer` to manage your `Application`, I would insist that you should use `AlarmManager` which is an inbuilt Android Facility that Android knows better. In `Timer` the problem can be that when Android seeks resources for any other Application or something like that it may kill your Timer thread and get the resources where as it won't kill the `AlarmManager` service that is running because that is what Android knows. You can check my question [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624270/autostart-application-not-working-properly) to get further idea.

Comment: ya Superb.i will try with Alarm  manager and contact with you as soon.and one more Question.if screen is locked,recevier is still running?

Comment: yes everything works fine in mycase as I had tried. But you should check it once in your case and which device you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Following source will help you to unlock the screen.I hope this will help you a bit.

```
KeyguardManager mKeyGuardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
     KeyguardLock mLock = mKeyGuardManager.newKeyguardLock("your_activity_name");
      mLock.disableKeyguard();
```

Comment: ya karthick am trying this.But my Application is for Customer purpose.Its not good for our requirements.is any other way to solve the problem