# Issues alarm manager in every 1 min Android?

Tags: android, alarm

I want to make a service which fire alarm manager in every 1 min interval..But 
 my Alarm run once(first time only).
I follow  [Lalit Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624270/autostart-application-not-working-properly)

```
private class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO); 
            AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent i=new Intent(context, ConnectionReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
            mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1*60*1000, pi);
        }
}
```

Comment: wants to discuss with you, please come back in chat room

Comment: Have you tried [Commonsware Example](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/SystemServices/Alarm/src/com/commonsware/android/syssvc/alarm/OnBootReceiver.java) Try this.

Comment: ya i tried Installing screen.apk...
[2012-01-25 13:03:30 - screen] Success!
[2012-01-25 13:03:30 - screen] \screen\bin\screen.apk installed on device
[2012-01-25 13:03:30 - screen] Done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Juts register broadcast receiver for:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK

Comment: again it comes first time only

Comment: This action is fired every minute by system.    Just register broadcast receiver for it in your manifest.  No need to set up alarm manager at all

Comment: from android doc: "You can not receive this through components declared in manifests, only by exlicitly registering for it with Context.registerReceiver()."

Answer (score 2):

Try this code in Your broadcast receiver's onReceive method

```
AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)ctxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                              60000+System.currentTimeMillis(),
                                  getPendingIntent(ctxt));
```

and you can get pending intent

```
private static PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Context ctxt) {
    Intent i=new Intent(ctxt, AReceiver.class);
    return(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt, 0, i, 0));
}
```

where AReceiver class is for start service like Notification
it is working fine in my app so i hope it helps you

Comment: cal means calender for Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();

Comment: and no permission need for this

Comment: where i have to start the task

Comment: You can start in any activity's onCreate method by calling particular receiver class

Comment: a complete tutorial is here http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html#receiver

Comment: my requirements i want to print a toast for every 1 minutes.where i have put the toast

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7025/discussion-between-trustme-and-ajay)

Comment: Put your toast in AReceiver class's on receive method

Comment: Why have you added `System.currentTimeMillis()` with interval time?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question already has an answer, but for others who have had the same issue but need to use `AlarmManager`. The reason why it only runs once is because the new `PendingIntent` you create does not get recreated, but rather is reusing the one before it. So in other words, the reason why your alarm only ran once was because it kept reusing it. Using the flags to refresh the intent extras if there are any should be doing the trick, but that also does not work.

A trick to use to make sure it does not reuse the `PendingIntent` and ultimately the `Intent` you provide is to use `setAction()` and give it some unique "Action". I did it like this:

```
intent.setAction("com.yourname."+System.currentTimeMillis());
```

As you see this makes sure its unique. Though, the above accepted answer it the best approach, if someone does not want that, they need to understand why and how to remedy that issue. Hope it helps anyone else.