# ScheduledExecutorService behavior on Android

Tags: java, android, jvm

I'm looking for Android specific implementation detail of ScheduledExecutorService.schedule when device is in deep sleep. I understand that schedule will not guarantee exact timing but simply execute "after" the delay. What I am not clear on is how sleep (and deep sleep?) is accounted in the timing. To be specific scenario:

Schedule a task an hour later
5mins in, the phone goes to sleep for 30mins
When do I expect the task to get scheduled?

Also if the phone wake up long after the scheduled time, is the task then scheduled for execution immediately?

Answer (score -1):

As far as this post says [Difference between AlarmManager and ScheduledExecutorService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558694/difference-between-alarmmanager-and-scheduledexecutorservice), it won't work in deep sleep mode. And I think it should be pretty simple to test it on an android device if you try to run a task after some arbitrary time and just wait for device to go in deep sleep mode.

Comment: You can find this post useful too: https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android/issues/346