# Android How to run a background service for every one minute in android?

Tags: android, service

I have two services in my Android app. In that I am running my services every single minute. but some mobile devices services are stopping, but it's not executing the `onDestroy()` method.

My question is how to run a service in every one minute without stopping. Because my app is completely depends on background service only.

I am using Timer Task. Please give me proper solution with TimerTask.

```
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        process();
    }
};
Timer mTimer = new Timer();
mTimer.schedule(timerTask, 0,60*1000);
```

process() Method is doing all the task. Its producing the notifications in app.

Comment: You need start your service when you powerON your device, you need to declare in your manifest, what are you using exactly?

Comment: Start service as STICKY. in onStartCommand which will start once it is killed. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY

Comment: you have to post you try code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073424/call-android-service-at-regular-intervals-goodapporach

Comment: Android offers AlarmManager to accomplish this type of tasks.So you can use that