# ScheduledExecutorService vs Timer vs Handler

Tags: android, concurrency, timer, java.util.concurrent

What are the pros and cons of using  `ScheduledExecutorService` / `Timer` / `Handler`? As I understand in Android instead of `Timer` it's need to use `Handler`, but what about `ScheduledExecutorService`?

As I understand `Handler` and `ScheduledExecutorService` is only for relative time, right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333680/android-schedule-action

Comment: Main difference between Timer and ScheduledExecutor: the latter can use several thread (via a thread pool) and remove the risk of one task delaying the next one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice

Comment: This shows a good clarification http://stackoverflow.com/a/6558821/1016544

Answer (score 5):

All three allow you to execute tasks on a different (eg. non-main) thread. The [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) allows you to use a message passing Actor pattern to communicate safely between thread. It does not allow you to do timing/delays/etc.

A [ScheduledExecutorService](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) is a very generic threading management solution. You initialize it with a certain number to worker threads and then give it work units. You can delay/time and repeat work units.

The [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) class has a simple API which resembles a ScheduledExecutorService for one-time, one-thread usage. The official API suggests to not use this class but roll your own ScheduledExecutor instead.

Comment: you can used Handler#postDelayed(Runnable, interval)